# Mysql table for friendship - design issue that resulted in complication while querying

Tags: mysql, sql

Instead of designing database with two records per relationship, I went with 1 row. And got myself into trouble!

This is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `friends` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id_1` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status_1` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_id_2` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status_2` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_rela` (`user_id_1`,`user_id_2`),
  KEY `user_id_2` (`user_id_2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=97 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I've several problems with this design.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6ccb8/2

First of all I cannot select status for current user. since current user can be anywhere in user_id_1 or user_id_2.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   friends.friend_id
FROM (
    SELECT created,
        CASE user_id_1 WHEN 1 THEN user_id_2 
            ELSE user_id_1 
        END AS friend_id
    FROM friends
    WHERE 1 IN (user_id_1, user_id_2)
) friends
ORDER BY friends.created DESC
```

Second problem I'm facing is update status of current user. If he accepts friendship, how do I update correct value in status_1 or status_2?

Are there solutions to this problem? or is it better if I go with simpler AB BA schema with two rows per relationship?

Comment: Er, it's your design. You tell us! I think it's important to consider how you want reciprocation to work - and what happens when one individual 'unfriends' another.

Comment: @Strawberry :) well I'm not particularly good with the design... just trying to learn...

Comment: OK, so why are there two statuses?

Comment: @Strawberry I've two status for each user, because it tells me which user is ok with relationship. If both accept both status will read 1. if user initiated friend request his status is set 1, while waiting for the other to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should review your design in order to have less columns and only 1 row per friendship:

should be something like this:

```
id    asker_user_id        asked_user_id        friendship_status        timestamp
198   21                   92                   NULL                     '2013-11-02 9:00:00'
199   27                   92                   1                        '2013-11-03 9:00:00'
198   91                   21                   0                        '2013-11-04 9:00:00'
```

Now I don't know how you want to manage your friendship statuses...

- Do you want to use a status table?
- Do you want to use a status as a bit where NULL is not yet answered, 1 is accepted and 0 is rejected?
- Do you want your timestamp to date the request, the answer or both ( then you would have 2 timestamp columns).

But only you will be able to make those design decisions.

Comment: My problem with this schema is following. Consider situation when two users asked eachother friendship but both initiated friend request. Than I will have two rows for this relationship where both users are asked and askers at the same time. How do i avoid that duplication?

Comment: Regarding your other questions. No I don't want to use status table. yes NULL not yet, 1 accepted, 0 rejected works fine for me. Dating request is sufficient.

Comment: @RedBalloon I don't think the duplication is such a problem. In fact it seems to be a good way of managing reciprocity.

Comment: You should programmatically avoid a user to request friendship if the concerned user already requested that friendship from "the other way"..

Comment: I disagree. I think you store it in the database. Otherwise you could (theoretically) create a race condition.

Comment: @Strawberry : Couldn't this be avoided by using a stored procedure / trigger on inserts in the table in order to update the status to 1 if both user requested friendship?

Comment: @FrancisP don't I go back to complications I was facing in my original table?

Comment: Maybe - I just don't think that's  how I'd do it. Doubling rows might not be perfect, but it IS only double.